# Preserve Styles in Microsoft Word 2016 Conditional Text

Tags: microsoft-word, conditional-statements

I have an MS Word document from which I need to create 2 subdocs for internal/public audiences. I am using the IF field to condionalize the master doc. In one section, the "truetext" contains a few paragraphs that have different paragraph styles, but when I generate the "true" version of the doc, all the content is there, but the paragraph styles are not observed. Is there a way to preserve the paragraph styles of the original text?

Thanks for any help!